# Responsive website works on Desktop, Android phone but breaks on iphone even after using the media query and view port meta tags

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design

Can someone help me understand why the site - https://amandeepsinghkhanna.github.io/about/ is responsive on the PC, on android phones but breaks on the iPhone. I have the media query as well as the viewport meta tag included in the code. It is hosted on GitHub-pages, if it helps in solving the issue.

Comment: Hello, in which iPhone device is it breaking? In most of the iPhones, its working fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, it is breaking on my iphone 11, but works on oneplus 5 and oneplus 6.

Comment: Hi, if I am not wrong, the viewport size of iphone 11 is 414x896 px. Can you please share a screenshot of what is breaking in your device?

Comment: @DhritimanTamuliSaikia here is the screenshot link - https://imgur.com/a/QFMuotA